# Can not sink to BigQuery using Dataflow Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have 2 csv files: expeditions- 2010s.csv and peaks.csv with the join key **'peak_id'**. I'm using notebook with Apache Beam in Dataflow to join them. Here is my code as below

```
def read_csv_file(readable_file):
    import apache_beam as beam
    import csv
    import io
    import datetime
    # Open a channel to read the file from GCS
    gcs_file = beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(readable_file)

    # Read it as csv, you can also use csv.reader
    csv_dict = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(gcs_file))

    for row in csv_dict:
        yield (row)

def run(argv=None):
    import apache_beam as beam
    import io
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        # This example file contains a total of only 10 lines.
        # Useful for developing on a small set of data.
        default='gs://bucket/folder/peaks.csv')
    
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input1',
        dest='input1',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        # This example file contains a total of only 10 lines.
        # Useful for developing on a small set of data.
        default='gs://bucket/folder/expeditions- 2010s.csv')

     
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    input_p1 = (
        p
         | 'Read From GCS input1' >> beam.Create([known_args.input1])
         | 'Parse csv file p1' >> beam.FlatMap(read_csv_file)
         | 'Tuple p1' >> beam.Map(lambda e: (e["peakid"], {'peakid': e["peakid"], 'bcdate': e["bcdate"], 'smtdate':e["smtdate"]}))
    )
    input_p2 = (
        p
         | 'Read From GCS input2' >> beam.Create([known_args.input])
         | 'Parse csv file p2' >> beam.FlatMap(read_csv_file)
         | 'Tuple p2' >> beam.Map(lambda e: (e["peakid"], {'peakid': e["peakid"], 'pkname': e["pkname"], 'heightm':e["heightm"]})) 
    )
    # CoGroupByKey: relational join of 2 or more key/values PCollection. It also accept dictionary of key value
    output = (
        (input_p1, input_p2)
        | 'Join' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
        | 'Final Dict' >> beam.Map(lambda el: to_final_dict(el[1]))
        # | beam.Map(print)
        | 'Write To BigQuery' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
           table='project:dataset.expeditions',
           method='FILE_LOADS',
           custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://bucket/folder/temp',
           create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)    
    )
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
    
def to_final_dict(list_tuple_of_tuple):
        result = {}
        for list_tuple in list_tuple_of_tuple:
            for el in list_tuple:
                result.update(el)
        return result


    # runner = DataflowRunner()
    # runner.run_pipeline(p, options=options)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I got the result before writing to BigQuery:

- {'peakid': 'TKRG', 'bcdate': '4/24/10', 'smtdate': '5/5/10', 'pkname': 'Takargo', 'heightm': '6771'}
- {'peakid': 'AMPG', 'bcdate': '4/5/10', 'smtdate': '', 'pkname': 'Amphu Gyabjen', 'heightm': '5630'}
- {'peakid': 'AMAD', 'bcdate': '1/27/20', 'smtdate': '2/2/20', 'pkname': 'Ama Dablam', 'heightm': '6814'}
- {'peakid': 'ANN1', 'bcdate': '3/27/19', 'smtdate': '4/23/19', 'pkname': 'Annapurna I', 'heightm': '8091'}
- ...

But it can't write to BigQuery with the error:
**RuntimeError: BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_602_215864ba592a2e01f0c4e2157cc60c47_51de5de53b58409da70f699c833c4db5 failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto
location: 'gs://bucket/folder/temp/bq_load/4bbfc44d750c4af5ab376b2e3c3dedbd/project.dataset.expeditions/25905e46-db76-49f0-9b98-7d77131e3e0d'
message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://bucket/folder/temp/bq_load/4bbfc44d750c4af5ab376b2e3c3dedbd/project.dataset.expeditions/25905e46-db76-49f0-9b98-7d77131e3e0d'
reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'Write To BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs']**

Comment: You just want to manipulate the csv Files and write the output to BigQuery? Then I'd say remove the `method` and `custom_gcs_temp_location` argument from `WriteToBigQuery` - those are not required.

Comment: Can you share the exact Json schema of your table please ? I think the problem is due to a bad formats on dates fields.

Comment: @CaptainNabla it's not working because no gcs location

Comment: @MazlumTosun is this what you want to ? ` [ { "name": "bcdate", "mode": "NULLABLE", "type": "DATE", "description": "%m/%d/%y", "fields": [] }, { "name": "smtdate", "mode": "NULLABLE", "type": "DATE", "description": "%m/%d/%y", "fields": [] }, { "name": "peakid", "mode": "NULLABLE", "type": "STRING", "fields": [] } ] ` and their data are formatted like: 3/6/10

Comment: @MazlumTosun you're right, there is an error with date fields. I remove them and it works. Do you have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the date format is not correct, use the following format for your date fields : `YYYY-MM-DD` => `2013-12-25` and normally it will solve your issue.